# correct context switching under x86-64 / Windows

Tags: c, windows, assembly, x86-64

I'm implementing my own fiber library for x86-64. It's partially motivated by lack of standard context switching across platforms (GCC/Linux has makecontext, which takes void *s as varargs, and Windows has its fiber API which takes 1 void * arg) as well as a learning exercise in API design and implementation. In my API, a coroutine function take 2 arguments: a coroutine context and a void * argument, so I'm learning how this works. I'll start with the calling API, which is C.

```
struct win64_mcontext {
  U64 rdi, rsi, rbx, rbp, r12, r13, r14, r15;
  U64 rax, rsp, rip;
  U64 rcx, rdx, r8, r9;
};

struct coroutine {
  struct win64_mcontext caller;
  struct win64_mcontext callee;
  U32 state;
};

void coprepare(struct coroutine **co,
           void *stack, U64 stack_size, cofunc_t func)
{
  *co = malloc(sizeof **co); /* TODO: replace with something cheaper */
  _coprepare(&(*co)->caller, &(*co)->callee, stack, stack_size, func);
}

void coenter(struct coroutine *co, void *enter_arg)
{
   _coenter(&co->caller, &co->callee, enter_arg);
}

void coyield(struct coroutine *co, void *yield_arg)
{
  _coyield(&co->callee, &co->caller, yield_arg);
}

int  coresume(struct coroutine *co)
{
  _coresume(&co->caller, &co->callee);
  return 0; /* punt this for now */
}
```

Here's the assembly that drives the whole thing. _coenter, _coyield and _coresume are all implemented as a `jmp __cotransfer`

```
;;; _coprepare(struct win64_mcontext *old, struct win64_mcontext *new,
;;;            void *stack, U64 stack_size,
;;;            cofunc_t func);
;;; RCX     -> old
;;; RDX     -> new
;;; R8      -> stack
;;; R9      -> stack_size
;;; RSP + ? -> func
_coprepare proc
    ;; save non-volatile GPRs in 'old'
    mov [RCX + OFF_RSI], RSI
    mov [RCX + OFF_RDI], RDI
    mov [RCX + OFF_RBP], RBP
    mov [RCX + OFF_RBX], RBX
    mov [RCX + OFF_R12], R12
    mov [RCX + OFF_R13], R13
    mov [RCX + OFF_R14], R14
    mov [RCX + OFF_R15], R15

    ;; save stack frame info in 'old'
    mov R10, RSP
    mov R11, OFFSET _coyield

    mov [RCX + OFF_RSP], R10
    mov [RCX + OFF_RIP], R11

    ;; init non-volatile GPRs in 'new'
    lea R10, [R8 + R9]       ; new RSP, = stack + stack_size
    lea R11, [RBP - 32]  ; load func

    xor EAX, EAX
    mov [RDX + OFF_RSI], RAX
    mov [RDX + OFF_RDI], RAX
    mov [RDX + OFF_RBX], RAX
    mov [RDX + OFF_RBP], R10
    mov [RDX + OFF_R12], RAX
    mov [RDX + OFF_R13], RAX
    mov [RDX + OFF_R14], RAX
    mov [RDX + OFF_R15], RAX

    mov [RDX + OFF_RSP], R10
    mov [RDX + OFF_RIP], R11

    ret
_coprepare endp

;;; __cotransfer(struct win64_context *old, struct win64_mcontext *new, void *trans_arg);
;;; RCX : old
;;; RDX : new
;;; R8  : trans_arg
__cotransfer proc
    ;; save non-volatile GPRs
    mov [RCX + OFF_RSI], RSI
    mov [RCX + OFF_RDI], RDI
    mov [RCX + OFF_RBX], RBX
    mov [RCX + OFF_RBP], RBP
    mov [RCX + OFF_R12], R12
    mov [RCX + OFF_R13], R13
    mov [RCX + OFF_R14], R14
    mov [RCX + OFF_R15], R15

    ;; save argument GPRs
    mov [RCX + OFF_RCX], RCX
    mov [RCX + OFF_RDX], RDX
    mov [RCX + OFF_R8], R8
    mov [RCX + OFF_R9], R9

    ;; save stack frame info
    lea R10, [RSP - 8]  ; save SP, exclude IP
    lea R11, [RSP]      ; save IP

    mov [RCX + OFF_RSP], R10
    mov [RCX + OFF_RIP], R11

    ;; switch stacks
    mov RAX, RSP
    mov RSP, [RDX + OFF_RSP]
    mov [RCX + OFF_RSP], RAX

    ;; load non-volatile GPRs
    mov RSI, [RDX + OFF_RSI]
    mov RDI, [RDX + OFF_RDI]
    mov RBX, [RDX + OFF_RBX]
    mov RBP, [RDX + OFF_RBP]
    mov R12, [RDX + OFF_R12]
    mov R13, [RDX + OFF_R13]
    mov R14, [RDX + OFF_R14]
    mov R15, [RDX + OFF_R15]

    ;; load argument registers
    mov R10, RCX
    mov R11, RDX

    mov RCX, [R11 + OFF_RCX]
    mov RDX, [R11 + OFF_RDX]
    mov R8,  [R11 + OFF_R8]
    mov R9,  [R11 + OFF_R9]

    ; push new return address
    mov RAX, [R11 + OFF_RIP]
    push RAX        
    ret ; jump to new return address
__cotransfer endp
```

Am I missing something? It always crashes somewhere in __cotransfer. I can't tell where I end up during debugging, so I must be doing something wrong, like mangling the BP or IP or SP. I lose the stack because I switched it and MSVC can't figure it out where we are now. I'm pretty lost and I need help from someone with experience with these sorts of things.

Comment: For starters, you trash R10 (with value of RSP) before you save it.  Usually a context switch saves *all* the registers.  (I've implemented a system where one saves only the necessary registers, and that's harder to do because you have to know or legislate the necessary context at each switch point.  I get the impression you want simple and robust to get past the learning experience, or maybe there's something you aren't telling us).

Comment: @Ira Baxter I'm pretty sure I use it before I trash it in __cotransfer. It's in the pairs of  `lea/mov` below the comment `;; save stack frame info`. I rewrite it's value when I do a `mov R11, RDX`. Are you taking about in _coprepare? Also, you're right on the money wrt to being simple and robust. I want to build a multithreaded job system on top of it. To do that robustly, the primitives must always do the work implied by the API.

Comment: why so not efficient and complex ? we need only 5 api - for convert thread <-> fiber (`ConvertThreadToFiber` and `ConvertFiberToThread`), for create new fiber (`CreateFiber`) delete fiber (`DeleteFiber`) and only **single** function for switch context (`SwitchToFiber`) - not need any `coenter`,`coyield`, `coresume`. in fiber context we need save only stackpointer (rsp/esp) and `NT_TIB` (windows specific). registers we can save in stack

Comment: Efficient and complex can come later. The problem we face just getting it working is we have little visibility into machine state. Once I get it working, I can optimize it. Most of these 'mov's can be executed in parallel because they are independent.

Comment: i mean that only single function for switch context (SwitchToFiber) - not need any coenter,coyield, coresume. not view any problem in implementation (assume that we save only basic registers), but what duplicate existing api functional ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by design we need 5 routines

- for convert current thread to fiber (allocate fiber context for
  current thread) and convert fiber to thread back (free this context)
- for create and delete new fiber context
- and single routine for switch context for selected fiber

in fiber context we need save the current stack pointer of fiber and pointer to it allocated stack (for free it, when we decide delete fiber). from windows view - we also must have own `NT_TIB` structure for every fiber and switch `StackBase`, `StackLimit`, etc when we switch fiber context. otherwise will be not work exception handle and additional allocation place in stack (conversion of reserved to committed memory and moving guard page). as result `NT_TIB` need also save in fiber context. the registers of fiber we can save direct in it stack.

minimal implementation for windows (of course exist ready implementation here) can look like:

c/c++ part:

```
typedef struct _INITIAL_TEB
{
    PVOID OldStackBase;
    PVOID OldStackLimit;
    PVOID StackBase;
    PVOID StackLimit;
    PVOID StackAllocationBase;
} INITIAL_TEB, *PINITIAL_TEB;

extern "C"
NTSYSAPI 
NTSTATUS 
NTAPI RtlFreeUserStack  (   _In_ PVOID      AllocationBase  );

extern "C"
NTSYSAPI 
NTSTATUS 
NTAPI   
RtlCreateUserStack (
                    _In_opt_ SIZE_T CommittedStackSize, 
                    _In_opt_ SIZE_T MaximumStackSize, 
                    _In_opt_ ULONG_PTR ZeroBits, 
                    _In_ SIZE_T PageSize, 
                    _In_ ULONG_PTR ReserveAlignment, 
                    _Out_ PINITIAL_TEB InitialTeb);

struct FIBER_CONTEXT
{
    NT_TIB Tib;
    PVOID StackPointer;
    PVOID StackAllocationBase;
};

extern "C"
{
    void __cdecl FiberStart();
    void __fastcall SwitchToContext(FIBER_CONTEXT* ctx);
}

FIBER_CONTEXT* MyConvertThreadToFiber()
{
    if (FIBER_CONTEXT* ctx = new FIBER_CONTEXT)
    {
        ((NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb())->FiberData = ctx;
        return ctx;
    }

    return 0;
}

void MyConvertFiberToThread()
{
    if (FIBER_CONTEXT* ctx = (FIBER_CONTEXT*)((NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb())->FiberData)
    {
        delete ctx;
        ((NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb())->FiberData = 0;
    }
}

FIBER_CONTEXT* WINAPI MyCreateFiber(
                          __in      SIZE_T dwStackSize,
                          __in      PFIBER_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
                          __in_opt  PVOID lpParameter
                          )
{
    INITIAL_TEB InitialTeb;
    NTSTATUS status = RtlCreateUserStack(0, dwStackSize, 0, 0x1000, 0x10000, &InitialTeb);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        if (FIBER_CONTEXT* ctx = new FIBER_CONTEXT)
        {
            ctx->StackAllocationBase = InitialTeb.StackAllocationBase;
            NT_TIB* Tib = ((NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb());

            ctx->Tib.ArbitraryUserPointer = 0;
            ctx->Tib.ExceptionList = 0;
            ctx->Tib.FiberData = ctx;
            ctx->Tib.StackBase = InitialTeb.StackBase;
            ctx->Tib.StackLimit = InitialTeb.StackLimit;
            ctx->Tib.SubSystemTib = Tib->SubSystemTib;
            ctx->Tib.Self = Tib->Self;

            void** StackBase = (void**)InitialTeb.StackBase;
            ctx->StackPointer = StackBase - (4 + 1 + 8);
            StackBase[-3] = lpStartAddress;
            StackBase[-4] = lpParameter;
            StackBase[-5] = FiberStart;
            return ctx;
        }
        RtlFreeUserStack(InitialTeb.StackAllocationBase);
    }

    return 0;
}

VOID WINAPI MyDeleteFiber(FIBER_CONTEXT* ctx)
{
    RtlFreeUserStack(ctx->StackAllocationBase);
    delete ctx;
}
```

asm (for x64) implementation part:

```
NT_TIB STRUCT
    ExceptionList DQ ?
    StackBase DQ ?
    StackLimit DQ ?
    SubSystemTib DQ ?
    FiberData DQ ?
    ArbitraryUserPointer DQ ?
    Self DQ ?
NT_TIB ENDS

FIBER_CONTEXT STRUCT
    Tib NT_TIB <?>
    StackPointer DQ ?
FIBER_CONTEXT ENDS

extern __imp_ExitThread:QWORD

_TEXT segment 'CODE'

FiberStart proc
    mov     rcx,[rsp]
    call    qword ptr [rsp + 8]
    mov     ecx,eax
    call    [__imp_ExitThread]
FiberStart endp

SwitchToContext proc
    push    r15
    push    r14
    push    r13
    push    r12
    push    rsi
    push    rdi
    push    rbx
    push    rbp

    mov     rax,gs:[NT_TIB.Self]    ; rax -> NT_TIB

    mov     rdx,[rax + NT_TIB.FiberData]    ; current fiber data

    mov     [rdx + FIBER_CONTEXT.StackPointer],rsp  ; save current rsp
    mov     rsp,[rcx + FIBER_CONTEXT.StackPointer]  ; set new rsp

    ; save NT_TIB
    lea     rdi,[rdx + FIBER_CONTEXT.Tib]
    mov     rsi,rax
    mov     rdx,rcx
    mov     rcx, SIZEOF NT_TIB / SIZEOF QWORD
    rep     movsq

    ; set NT_TIB
    mov     rdi,rax
    lea     rsi,[rdx + FIBER_CONTEXT.Tib]
    mov     rcx, SIZEOF NT_TIB / SIZEOF QWORD
    rep     movsq

    pop     rbp
    pop     rbx
    pop     rdi
    pop     rsi
    pop     r12
    pop     r13
    pop     r14
    pop     r15
    ret
SwitchToContext endp

_TEXT ENDS

END
```

and example of use:

```
struct FCTX 
{
    FIBER_CONTEXT* MainFiber, *WorkFiber;
    PCSTR sz;
};

void WINAPI FiberProc(FCTX* ctx)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        DbgPrint("%s\n", ctx->sz);
        SwitchToContext(ctx->MainFiber);
    }
}

void test()
{
    FCTX ctx;
    if (ctx.MainFiber = MyConvertThreadToFiber())
    {
        if (ctx.WorkFiber = MyCreateFiber(0, (PFIBER_START_ROUTINE)FiberProc, &ctx))
        {
            ctx.sz = "task #1";
            SwitchToContext(ctx.WorkFiber);
            ctx.sz = "task #2";
            SwitchToContext(ctx.WorkFiber);
            MyDeleteFiber(ctx.WorkFiber);
        }
        MyConvertFiberToThread();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good work, but I don't like the ConvertThreadToFiber and ConvertThreadToFiber calls. Windows has those, which is why I'm not using it. I like the idea of not newing when I could reuse fiber/coroutine contexts, as well as stacks.

Comment: @JesseLactin - every fiber must have own context. because this and need allocate context for current fiber. without this - you can not swap back from fiber to current thread.

Comment: @JesseLactin - *I like the idea of not newing when I could reuse fiber/coroutine contexts, as well as stacks* - and so what ? how this related to my implementation ? how many fibers is allocate. when it free, etc - absolute unrelated here

Comment: Where is RtlCreateUserStack and RtlFreeUserStack? I'm getting unresolved linker errors from copying your answer. Specifically, on those two functions. MSVC labels the offending functions as __imp_RtlCreateUserStack and __imp_RtlFreeUserStack in MyCreateFiber.

Comment: @JesseLactin - this functions exported by `ntdll.dll`. use `ntdllp.lib` or `ntdllp.lib`. of course, if want, you can use say VirtualAlloc/VirtualFreee for stack allocation. can just commit all stack as is. this Rtl api - reserve stack space, commit only small part or it and set guard page

Comment: I prefer to use that than implement the exact same thing with VirtualAlloc/VirtualProtect. Is RtlCreateUserStack and RtlFreeUserStack not available under Windows 10 x64? I'm still getting LNK2019 that flags Rtl[Create|Free]UserStack as the culprits after linking ntdll.dll.

Comment: @JesseLactin - of course this api is available. how i say you need use `ntdll.lib` or `ntdllp.lib` . but anyway this is not central part. you can simply allocate stack (commit all pages just) with `VirtualAlloc` and free with `VirtualFree`. in this case will be `StackLimit = StackAllocationBase = VirtualAlloc` and `StackBase` - top of allocated memory (`StackAllocationBase + stackSize`)

Comment: @JesseLactin - *as the culprits after linking ntdll.dll* - you use `ntdll[p].lib` ? this api is exist here , except you use very old `ntdll.lib` (may be from xp, but not exist x64 xp)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172132/discussion-between-jesse-lactin-and-rbmm).