# Replacing the call-stack of an application

Tags: windows, assembly, winapi, x86-64, backtrace

Is it at all possible to temporarily replace the call-stack, as in the RSP-register, while running an x64 application on windows? I thought that I could achieve this while using a frame-pointer register (R14):

```
push        r14  
sub         rsp,28h  
mov         r14,rsp  
mov         rsp,qword ptr [rcx]
```

Here, "rcx" is an argument of a struct "Stack", that contains a "void*" to the memory I want to use. However, this seems to cause issues. Immediately after overwriting RSP, while debugging (in VS using the disassembler-window), the entire call-stack in the callstack-window goes missing, minus the address of the current function:

[image]

This happens specifically when setting RSP to my own stacks address. This address is 16-byte aligned. The stack is setup via VirtualAlloc with 3MB of address-space, 4kb of initial commited space and guard-pages on both sides to check for overflow/stack growth. The stack is setup in the correct direction, where "sub" is used to grow. I also did setup the frame-pointer in the unwind information correctly (including the correct epilogue), as the following will work as expected:

```
push        r14  
sub         rsp,28h  
mov         r14,rsp // end of prolog
mov         rbx,rcx 
sub         rsp,80h // callstack still intact
```

Is there anything else I need to do; or is this simply impossible to do? It's not only an issue of the display-window, when executing the call it will crash somewhere further down the line (hard to pinpoint without any working stacktrace).

**Background**

As for why I need this: I have a IL based visual scripting language, for which I wrote a native compiler-backend. The language itself is used for games and heavily based on "coroutines"/the ability to yield, with most of the code actually utilizing this feature. It To make this as performant as possible, any yielding-function actually get's a smaller side-loaded stack (that is setup similar to what I described above, but with less reserved space), and executes using this stack (similar to what I belive a thread has). On yield, the stack is simply perserved until resume; and when done, it is returned to a pool where it can be reused.

Yielding can also happen on nested method calls, seamlessly, by simply having their return-addresses stored on the stack.

This worked pretty easily when running in an interpreter. Native code posed additional challenges, but most have been solved. Yield-Resume is implemented with a fake function prolog followed by a jmp to the resume-address. However, I still have to use the interpreters stack manually to manage the return-addresses, which is slower and causes issues with the ability to get correct stack-traces.

So my solution for this would be to replace RSP with my own stack-pointer for the duration of the yielding call. Then, I could simply "call" nested yielding functions normally, with their return-addresses now placed on my stack, but with the native instructions. When I resume, I could simply restore rsp to the point it beforehand, and everything should fall into place... except the system seems to not like me replacing RSP, as stated above.

Anyway, this is just to answer the "why" I would need to do this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science)

Comment: yes, possible swap user stack. you can convert thread to fiber and create additionals fibers. or even can do this manual, you need also adjust `StackBase` and `StackLimit` in `NT_TIB`.

Comment: @harold Should have made it more clear, I have a custom assembler, which creates its own UNWIND_INFO structure, so there are no directives in this disassembly. They are however set, which you were able to verify.

Comment: @RbMm Doing the stack-adjustment manually is preferable for me. How do I adjust the NT_TIB values. Is it enough just to set them via accessing "(NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb()"?

Comment: What's the problem? You completely replaced the call stack and the debugger is showing a completely replaced call stack? Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @user253751 My expectation was that using a frame-pointer register would allow the debugger (and by extension, stack-trace libraries) to still trace the original stack back. Similar to how when we use alloca without a frame-pointer, the environment has no idea where we are (resulting in the same "bug"). With a frame-pointer, we can grow the stack arbitrarily. So I though that unwind would apply what is in the frame-pointer register to get back to the original stack; which it seems not to be able to do. FWIW fibres have the same behaviour; which is not what I intend here to happen.

Comment: via accessing "(NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb()"?  - yes

Comment: you can use something like [that](https://github.com/rbmm/Proxy/blob/main/MProxy.cpp#L50) or another [implementation](https://github.com/rbmm/Proxy/blob/main/FProxy.cpp) use `SwitchToFiber`

Comment: Windows (and Linux) don't use RBP frame-pointer backtracing by default, they use stack-unwind metadata.  (Although at least on Linux, it's possible for the metadata to indicate that this function uses RBP as a traditional frame pointer, pointing at a saved-RBP next to a return address, so more metadata isn't needed for each RSP change.  If you change RSP without changing RBP, I guess there's reason to hope that backtracing would look into the old stack.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I was aware of that. I did set R14 as the frame-pointer through the unwind-metadata. The UWOP_SET_FPREG is generated for the instruction that stores rsp in r14. and r14 is specified in the UNWIND_INFO.frameRegister-field. Not sure why I didn't use RBP, I can try to change it to see if it makes a difference. I know that my metadata in itself is correct though. As mentioned, I can effectively do "alloca" without problems, and if I remove the frame-pointer then the same "lost stack" happens.

Comment: Ok, yeah that should work, I wasn't aware that there was a choice of FP reg.  Does the metadata also give a choice of the offset from the FP register to the saved-FP / return address pair?  GCC for `-mabi=ms` does `push rbp`/`mov rbp, rsp` so it's pointing at the saved RBP, but MSVC (in a function with _alloca) does `push rbp` / `sub rsp, 48` / `lea rbp, [rsp+32]` so RBP is pointing 16 bytes below that for some reason.  https://godbolt.org/z/85o68a6dT  . vs. yours pointing 32 bytes below, which I assume you encode in your metadata for it to work correctly.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was using the definition of the frame-pointer offset from MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exception-handling-x64?view=msvc-170), which I interpreted as meaning that you encoding whatever [RSP+offset] you move into the frame-pointer. Since I just "mov r14,rsp", the offset should be 0; which is what I encoded.

Comment: Oh, I see, the distance between the initial RSP (pointing at return address) and RSP when you establish a frame pointer is set by previous directives like `.pushreg r14` and `.allocstack 28h` (or the equivalent if not using MASM) for the `push r14`, and the `sub rsp,28h` between `push r14` and `mov r14, rsp`.  So yes, `.setframe r14, 0` is appropriate.  So the metadata design apparently is flexible enough to handle that.

Comment: @PeterCordes Seems so. Unfortunately it does not seem to like replacing RSP without a full context switch. After some digging I found that the StackWalker library will produce a correct callstack when executed after me setting RSP. Unfortuntely though, the unwind/exception-handler I registered (RtlAddFunctionTable) are not being executed in this state. Which means, unless I find some more thing to fix it, I cannot do what I wanted to do, probably due to some bug or limitation in the x64 windows ABI.

Comment: @Juliean if do correct switch rsp, exceptions still work ok. it work and with SwitchToFiber  and in case custom switch, if you correct set new stack limits in TEB

Comment: @RbMm When I use a fiber to execute the code, it does work. When I do it myself, I have no luck. https://pastebin.com/gU38MzbY This is the ASM that is executed, alongside with the function to switch the thread-settings. I verified that all values in the function, and what get's set in RSP is correct. I have one last idea - maybe it's because I except in the same function that set RSP, fiber seem to set the environment before actually calling the code. Other than that, I'm at a loss.

Comment: (Works w/o the RSP set line as expected. Setting the NT_TIB has some effect though - if I set it without modifying RSP, the exception will lead to some stack-error. Though for the case where I set RSP, nothing is changed).

Comment: i dont know what you trying to, but if do without errors, all will be work.

Comment: @RbMm See my answer, the problem was me using a frame-pointer to point to the old stack (registered in the unwind-info), this was causing the exception-handler to not be executed.

Comment: @Juliean really "frame-pointer" - no such thing. and this is absolute unrelated to stack swap

Comment: @RbMm You can set a a frame-pointer in x86_64, and my original thought was that you could undo the stack-swap via this (as when I register RBX as frame-pointer in the unwind-code, it will restore RSP automatically when unwinding). That was before I know you had to switch the NT_TIB values as well; I guess I could have figured that this means you cannot (mis)use a frame-pointer register for it, but oh well.

Comment: again - no such thing as frame-pointer. this is very "soft" thing. and this is absolute unrelated to stack/context swap at all. this is your error. every function by self can use some register as "frame-pointer" or not use it at all.

Comment: @RbMm Probably a communication issues, I was refering to what can be registeres as "frame register" in x64 unwind, as via (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exception-handling-x64?view=msvc-170). And I do understand that it cannot be used to switch a stack, but is it really that absurd to someone who doesn't know the absolut details, to think that using an unwind-register that is explicitely used to restore a RSP that has been modified to an unknown value; to also be able to use this to actually restore RSP to the old stack? It seems logical on the surface.

Comment: FWIW StackWalker, as mentioned, does agree, and can use my R14/RBX to create a full trace even beyond the switched stack. Only x64 doesn't allow it to be used that way.,

Comment: you not need any "frame register", StackWalker, and of course stack trace will be only for single fiber shown at time. you can use system ready api for create fibers (i think best option) or by self implement this functional. every fiber have self stack and it pointer saved in fiber struct. when you need switch to another fiber - you save current stack pointer, in current fiber. than read new stack pointer from new fiber and set new stack. all. possible also push/pop all another registers from stack, however in general this not need, every function by self preserve non volatile registers

Comment: so forget about "frame pointer", you need replace only rsp/esp. all

Comment: @RbMm Yes, I do understand now what I need to do (also thanks to your explanations). I was just describing what I did wrong and why I came to that conclusion. Not having a full stacktrace is a bit suboptimal for my case, as I don't want full fiber (where execution is detached from source of SwitchFiber), but more what a coroutine would do. But I can work around that. now that all else works.

Comment: Not having a full stacktrace  - this and must not be, if you use another stack. trace must be only inside 1 stack

Comment: @RbMm Natively, it makes sense, but it's a bit worse for diagnostic. In case of an error or printing stack, I want to know the "full" trace. But I can probably do that by extending StackWalker to look at the original stack when it encounters the type of function where the stack is changed; similar to how I'd need to restore the stack in case of an exception. This should not cause any issues, it's just merging both call-stacks manually.

Comment: this look like you want view stack of 2 or more separate thread at once. by fact - every stack - separate thread.

Comment: @RbMm Not really like threads. What I do is essentially a stackfull coroutine. Each coroutine has it's own stack, and after the coroutine is done (or suspended), it will return to the previous point of execution, all the time - so not like a thread or fiber. So at least for diagnostics, both stacks give effectively one trace.

Comment: what you are doing is fibers exactly, but you not want use ready api for it. but not matter you use api or custom implementation. all this is "threads"by sense

Answer (score 3):

Okayy, after wasting a whole day on it, I found the answer. Thanks to everyone who commented. I'll try to break down the steps to fix:

1. First, I needed to make absolutely sure that there is enough shadow-space available in the new stack for any upcoming function-call, and that it is aligned. That fixes the initial crashes that I had.
2. Second, as RbMm pointed out, we need to set the threads StackBase/StackLimit-parameters. This can be done with a function:

   auto* pX = (NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb();

   pX->StackBase = state.stack.GetTop();
   pX->StackLimit = state.stack.GetBottom();
3. Using RtlCreateUserStack, which is a function that you have to define yourself, and include ntdll.lib for; helps with creating the stack. There was some additional issue with my own stack-creation, that made certain calls crash. See [correct context switching under x86-64 / Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575559/correct-context-switching-under-x86-64-windows) for details.
4. Lastly, you must not, I repeat, **must not use a frame-pointer register to point to the old stack**! I thought I was clever, but I was wrong. At least on windows, this seems to entirely confuse the unwind-handler; to a point where it will not be able to resolve the exception no matter what the state of the thread-values are.

5.) Then, once you are done you need to manually restore the stack before the epilogue. You also need to do the same thing in the exception-handler, obviously. At least in my case, I need exceptions to actually propagate through this. ... I haven't actually implemented it out, but I HOPE that I should be able to properly restore the stack in the custom Rtl exception-handler that I generated.

Unfortunately, the point 4) means that, yes, you won't have any callstack back to before the call the replaced the stack. This is consistent with using the WinAPI SwitchFiber - only in that place it makes sense, since you are deferring execution similar to a thread. For me, I'd prefer a callstack similar to a coroutine, but as it's only in the VisualStudio window...
Well, almost. When I was using the frame-pointer, the StackWalker-library was still able to show a valid stack-trace. Since I want to have at least the full traces in case of errors; I'll have to come up with a custom solution, though I'm confident this is easier to do then try to get the unwind-handler to execute the exception-handler...

Sorry, long post. But in case anyone ever needs to do what I did... that's really hard to figure out on your own. I'm just happy to have made some progress, even though the full implementation is not yet done.